# Sass recursion mixin

Tags: recursion, sass

I would like to know, if in sass is allowed to write a recursion mixin like this Less example :

```
.size($val) when ($val < 200 ) {
    width: $val;
    height: $val;
   .size($val + 50px);
}
```

I'm trying something like this, but i don't have any output

```
@mixin test($val) {
  width: $val;
  height: $val;
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    @include test($val);
  }
}
.block {
  @include test(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sass, you can create recursive functions, but your example is wrong.

Looking at your code, I see that you are in infinite loop, because *$var* variable is not used in the *@for* iterator. You only iterates from 1 to 5 infinitely.

The recursive approach here is the same as another languages, you have to use the parameter to call the function again, and when this variable is the same as 0 (for example), returns a value ... its value is used to the last call of the function to set the new value ... and again the first step.

Here are examples of Sass recursive functions:

- https://gist.github.com/paramburu/9613303
- http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/#section-3

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike your LESS example, your Sass mixin does not have a way to break out of the loop.

```
@mixin test($val) {
  width: $val;
  height: $val;
  @if $val > 0 {
    @include test($val - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think this function needs a @return to works fine. What do you think?

Comment: This isn't a function, its a mixin.  `@return` is a construct for functions.